# Install ImageMagic and Imagick via Brew

Tags: php, xampp, imagemagick, imagick

I'm trying to install Imagick on my XAMPP server, but am having some problems.

I installed `php55`, `ImageMagick` and `php55-imagick` via Homebrew, and restarted my XAMPP server. I assumed that XAMPP server would automatically pick up on the Imagick extension, but I was wrong.

Here's what I've tried:

- Modifying `php.ini` in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini` to include `extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.9/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/imagick.so"`
- Modifying `php.ini` in `/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php.ini` to include `extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.9/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/imagick.so"`
- Restarted XAMPP several times

I also created a `test.php` to see if the extension was loaded but was returned with an error.

```
<?php

if(extension_loaded('imagick')) {
echo 'Imagick Loaded';
} else {
echo 'error';
}
?>
```

My XAMPP server is running PHP 5.5.6, but executing `php -i` from bash returned:

> PHP 5.4.17 (cli) (built: Aug 25 2013 02:03:38)

I suspect there may be some conflicts with the PHP versioning... Would appreciate your help in setting this up!

**Update 1:** Not sure if I need to say this, I've to use PHP 5.5.6.

**Update 2:** Ran `./php -i | grep imagick` at `/Applications/XAMPP/bin`. Output returned:

```
imagick
imagick module => enabled
imagick module version => 3.1.2
imagick classes => Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator
imagick.locale_fix => 0 => 0
imagick.progress_monitor => 0 => 0
```

Imagick is enabled, but my test.php still returns an error and does not show in `phpinfo()`

Comment: are you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try changing `extension=` to `extension_dir=` in php.ini